# Push Notifications not working in Firebase 4.0

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I updated my pods today to the new Firebase 4.0. I went through the suggested changes and grabbed code from the Github example. I will be honest I am at a loss, I take the FCM Token and send a message from the firebase console and I get nothing.

I refresh and it says the message was sent but I check the console and the device and nothing is there. What am I missing?

Here is my appdelegate:

```
//
//  Created by Erik Grosskurth on 4/24/17.
//

import UIKit
import FirebaseAnalytics
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications
import SystemConfiguration
import MobileCoreServices
import Quickblox
import QuickbloxWebRTC


let kQBApplicationID:UInt = 3545252534
let kQBAuthKey = "udfgsegsetrgsextr"
let kQBAuthSecret = "setbsetbsetbsetrbset"
let kQBAccountKey = "sbrtsbrtbsrtbsrtbrt"

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // [START register_for_notifications]

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization( options: authOptions, completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        if (Messaging.messaging().fcmToken != nil) {
            DataModel.sharedInstance.sessionInfo.FirebaseAccessToken = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken!
            print("FCM token: \(DataModel.sharedInstance.sessionInfo.FirebaseAccessToken)")
        }else {
            print("token was nil")
        }

        // [END register_for_notifications]

        //Quickblox config
        QBSettings.setApplicationID(kQBApplicationID)
        QBSettings.setAuthKey(kQBAuthKey)
        QBSettings.setAuthSecret(kQBAuthSecret)
        QBSettings.setAccountKey(kQBAccountKey)

        // Set settings for zone
        QBSettings.setApiEndpoint("https://api.quickblox.com", chatEndpoint: "chat.quickblox.com", forServiceZone: .production)
        // Activate zone
        QBSettings.setServiceZone(.production)

        QBSettings.setKeepAliveInterval(30)
        QBSettings.setAutoReconnectEnabled(true)
        QBRTCConfig.setStatsReportTimeInterval(1)
        QBRTCConfig.setDialingTimeInterval(5)
        QBRTCConfig.setAnswerTimeInterval(60)

        return true
    }

    // [START receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        print(userInfo)

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)

    }


    // when APNs has assigned the device a unique token
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

        print("didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken()")

        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken

        //Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: MessagingAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
        //Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: MessagingAPNSTokenType.prod)
        //Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: MessagingAPNSTokenType.unknown)

        let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
        DataModel.sharedInstance.sessionInfo.APNSAccessToken = deviceTokenString
        print("APNS Access Token: \(deviceTokenString)")

    }


    // [END receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }


    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        QBChat.instance().disconnect { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error: \(String(describing: error))")
            } else {
                print("success for applicationDidEnterBackground")
            }
        }
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        let qbUser = QBUUser()
        qbUser.id = DataModel.sharedInstance.qbLoginParams.id
        qbUser.password = DataModel.sharedInstance.sessionInfo.QBPassword
        QBChat.instance().connect(with: qbUser) { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error: \(String(describing: error))")
            } else {
                print("success for applicationWillEnterForeground")
            }
        }
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        QBChat.instance().disconnect { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error: \(String(describing: error))")
            } else {
                print("success for applicationWillTerminate")
            }
        }
    }

    // LOCK IN PORTRAIT MODE
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask(rawValue: UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait.rawValue)
    }

}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    // [START refresh_token]
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        DataModel.sharedInstance.sessionInfo.FirebaseAccessToken = fcmToken
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
    }
    // [END refresh_token]
    // [START ios_10_data_message]
    // Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
    // To enable direct data messages, you can set Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
    // [END ios_10_data_message]
}
```

Here are the logs:

```
2017-05-31 16:49:56.937067-0400 Telemed[1843:937699] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS003016] Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy is disabled. To log deep link campaigns manually, call the methods in FIRAnalytics+AppDelegate.h.
2017-05-31 16:49:56.937 Telemed[1843] <Warning> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS003016] Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy is disabled. To log deep link campaigns manually, call the methods in FIRAnalytics+AppDelegate.h.
2017-05-31 16:49:57.023568-0400 Telemed[1843:937706] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS005000] The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function properly. Learn more at 
2017-05-31 16:49:57.023 Telemed[1843] <Warning> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS005000] The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function properly. Learn more at 
2017-05-31 16:49:57.028454-0400 Telemed[1843:937697] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.4000000 started
2017-05-31 16:49:57.028 Telemed[1843] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.4000000 started
2017-05-31 16:49:57.029042-0400 Telemed[1843:937697] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see )
2017-05-31 16:49:57.029 Telemed[1843] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see )
FCM token: myTokenIsHere
2017-05-31 16:49:57.101756-0400 Telemed[1843:937699] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS032003] iAd framework is not linked. Search Ad Attribution Reporter is disabled.
2017-05-31 16:49:57.102 Telemed[1843] <Warning> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS032003] iAd framework is not linked. Search Ad Attribution Reporter is disabled.
2017-05-31 16:49:57.103700-0400 Telemed[1843:937697] [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled
2017-05-31 16:49:57.103 Telemed[1843] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled
Destroyed Session but Saved Login
2017-05-31 16:49:57.158678-0400 Telemed[1843:937637] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-05-31 16:49:57.159102-0400 Telemed[1843:937637] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken()
APNS Access Token: 091F01B...
```

**>>>------> **SOLVED** <-------<<<**

*FOR A DEEP DIVE INTO THE TROUBLESHOOTING AND THE ULTIMATE FACEPALM AT THE END... FOLLOW THIS THREAD:* 
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/290

SPECIAL THANKS TO [THE RIZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9849/rizwan-sattar) FOR HIS TIME IN FIGURING OUT THE ISSUE!!

Comment: I'm assuming you've uploaded your APN key to the Firebase Console and you've checked the app settings on your device to make sure notifications aren't disabled?

Comment: Yes, but worth double checking as I haven't done it since long before the update

Comment: You're not the first person I've seen (today?) that has been having issues. Might want to put a star on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250823/sending-ios-notifications-from-firebase-or-another-platform-to-specific-termin

Comment: LOL Someone just grammar naziedited my question. Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging is quite complex to get set up correctly on iOS, because you have to ensure that your APNs configuration is working, and then add FCM on top of that.

#### APNs Setup

APNs Authentication Keys are also really nice by apple because they don't expire, works in both sandbox and production environments, and the same key (as a `.p8` file) can be used to send push notifications to *all* apps under that Apple Developer account.

It also introduces a new area for a potential failure: **typos**. You can type in a random bundle id, and as long as the right "team" is configured in Xcode, your app will happily get an APNs device token.

Sending a notification to that device token via APNs (I used [this script](http://thrysoee.dk/apns/) to send test notifications over HTTP/2 + Auth Keys) will yield a `DeviceTokenNotForTopic` error, so that should help you figure out what went wrong.

**Checklist**

- Ensure your app bundle id matches the bundle id you're sending to
- Ensure you have an entitlements file, with at least an `aps-environment` key set to `development` (this is automatically updated for you in release builds, by Xcode)
- If using "automatic" configuration (i.e. swizzling) in other SDKs like Firebase, make sure you're getting an APNs token in `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:`. That at least confirms that your APNs set up is okay (but still you might have a typo)

#### FCM Setup

Be sure that the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file you're using is for the same app as the `BUNDLE_ID` key in the plist. I've seen developers think that because APNs Keys should work just fine across all of their apps, that the same `GoogleService-Info.plist` is fine across apps, but that's not the case.

**Testing**

I'd also recommend sending yourself test notifications using [FCM's HTTP API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) from Terminal, to help debug the issue. Unlike the Firebase Notifications Console, it will give you any raw errors it encounters. Here's an example:

```
curl -X "POST" "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send" \
     -H "Authorization: key=SERVER_KEY" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d $'{
  "notification": {
    "body": "Testing with direct FCM API",
    "title": "Test Message",
    "badge": "0",
    "sound": "default"
  },
  "registration_ids": [
    "FCM_TOKEN"
  ]
}'
```

Fill in your `SERVER_KEY` with the value in your Firebase Console > Project Settings > Cloud Messaging > Server Key. Replace `FCM_TOKEN` with your FCM token.

I use [Paw](https://paw.cloud/) to send test notifications to my apps when I'm working on the FCM SDK.

Comment: Any idea why I might get the error "success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

Comment: ah, I was using the APN token (from apple) instead of the firebase token (which is different), that's why

Comment: @aman can you share code which token is to be used I am facing this issue from last 4 weeks still no resolution. can you help

Comment: @Abhishek - func request_access_to_send_push_notifications(_ app:UIApplication)
  {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound])
    { (granted, error) in
      // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
    }
    app.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    
  }

Comment: @Abhishek 

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
  {
     // ..
    if let me = Auth.auth().currentUser
    {
     
      request_access_to_send_push_notifications(application)
    }
   //..
}

Comment: @Abhishek 

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String)
  {
    let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let settings = db.settings
    settings.areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = true
    db.settings = settings
    let usersRef = db.collection("users").document(my_user_id)
    usersRef.setData(["fcm":fcmToken], merge:true)
    { err in
     
    }
  }

Comment: @Abhishek then use the FCM token when trying to send push notifications that is stored on your user in your user database.

Answer (score 0):

I was using .p8 file for sending notification, though notification wasn't coming; then I realised the Apple Push Notifications service (APNs) wasn't enabled under .p8 file.

After enabling it, all seems to work now.
[image]